# Java RMI return reference to remote object without binding

Tags: java, rmi, remoteobject, rmiregistry

I have a server and a client communicating through RMI. Their goal is to share a simple object, work on it together, and then simulate a server disconnect.

The sever has its name bound to the rmiregistry. The client uses the rmiregistry to get a remote reference to the server. Then it uses this reference to call a method that returns a reference to the object they will share. Further communication is to be done through this shared object.

The shared object is a UnicastRemoteObject, the server owns its implementation and has a method the returns a reference to the client.

The client knows the interface of the shared object, gets a remote reference from the server and then acts on it. Please note the server should return a remote reference, not a serialized copy.

This is the shared object interface

```
public interface CInterface extends Remote {
    boolean testMethod() throws RemoteException;
}
```

And this is its implementation

```
public class CImpl implements CInterface {
    @Override
    public boolean testMethod() throws RemoteException {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the method of the server that should return a remote reference when the client calls it

```
public CInterface exportRefToC() throws RemoteException {
    return new CImpl();
}
```

If I call it from the client, it gives me this exception

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested
>   exception is:     java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted;
>   java.io.NotSerializableException: sandbox.CImpl

I can get the method to work and return a remote reference if I write it this way

```
public CInterface exportRefToC() throws RemoteException {
    refToC = new CImpl();
    return (CInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(refToC, 1099);
}
```

What I don't get is why I need to go through the registry again, though not explicitly binding a the name, just to return a remote reference. The client got a reference to the server before, using the rmiregistry, so the bootstrap is done. Now, why can't the server just return a reference to the client without knowing the port of the rmiregistry (1099)?

Bonus question, if the server wants to make the object it shared with the client unavailable (to simulate a disconnection), is there a better way than doing this

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(refToC, true);
```

EDIT: if I extend the UnicastRemoteObject in the implementation of the shared object, the first version of the method works, however, the unexport does not work and return this exception

> java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread;
>   nested exception is:  java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: object not
>   exported

EDIT2: checked again, it does work, just need to save the reference before returning it

```
public CInterface exportRefToC() throws RemoteException {
    refToC = new CImpl();
    return refToC;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The shared object is a `UnicastRemoteObject`

No it isn't. Look again:

```
public class CImpl implements CInterface
```

Add `extends UnicastRemoteObject` to that, and provide an appropriate constructor, and your problem will disappear.

You don't need to call `exportObject(),` and you don't need a second binding to the Registry.

Your last question embodies a mistake. It should be `unexportObject(),` and that is the correct way of making the object unavailable.